# what is the role played by the group in group action?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

$H = Z_5 $ and $G = S_5$ and let $A =\{1,2,3,4,5 \} .$

My question is

1.What is difference between the the action of H on A and G on A ?

2.How many group actions are possible in the above a cases ?

Let us take $a \in H ,$ then there is permutation $\sigma _ a$ acting on A. I can define $\sigma _a : A \rightarrow A $ by $\sigma_a(x) = a+x.$

My Doubt is that is this the only operation we can use for the action. I have used addition since $Z_5$ is a group under addition modulo 5.

Answer (score 1):

Actions of $H$, say, on $A$ are described by homomorphisms $H \to S_{A} \cong S_{5}$.

In the first case, you can fix a generator $g$ of $H$, and the above homomorphism is described by the element $\gamma$ of $S_{5}$ to which you are mapping it. Now $\gamma$ must have order dividing $5$, so either it is the identity, or it has order $5$. Plently of choices, then. But you may want to consider actions *up to [similarities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Morphisms_and_isomorphisms_between_G-sets)*, and then the number drops quite drastically.

In the second case, you are considering homomorphisms $S_{5} \to S_{5}$. One is the trivial one, others have $A_{5}$ as its kernel (there are as many as there are involutions in $S_{5}$), and then there are the faithful ones (there are as many as there are automorphisms of $S_{5}$). Again, considering actions *up to similarities* is possibly the most sensible thing here.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way to regard action will allow you to see how many actions are possible:  an action of a group $G$ on a set $A$ is the same as specifying a homomorphism of groups $\phi\colon G\to \mathrm{Perm\,}(A)$. where Perm(A) is the collection of all permutationa of the set A, regarded as a group wrt composition of functions.

Comment: @Vanchinathan regarding that second part of the question, we can define only addition operation on the action of  H on A . Is that true ?